# EEVEE how to disable background light

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, world

I‘m currently having an issue. I want to disable the background light so that objects won‘t be influenced by it. In Cycles this is easy: inside the „Ray Visibility“ option of the world tab you just disable everything except „Camera“ and the background will immediately stop casting light into the scene. However I don‘t know how this should be done in EEVEE. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Add a *Light path node* to World shader, then connect "Is Camera Ray" to the strength input of the *Background* node.

[image]

Comment: Smart, never occured to me to do just that :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean disable the global light in EEVEE?

Change the surface color to totally black might help.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Yes, I mean the global light. But if I turn it entirely black (as in your picture), then I‘ll also just have a black background. What I want is to have a colored background that doesn‘t emit light.